# Looking for real world Gradle examples

Tags: build, gradle

I am currently trying out Gradle on some projects and I am looking for some real world examples of its usage. For example you can see Spring's Gradle configuration [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework). Can anyone suggest some other examples please?

Comment: (WARNING: Shameless self promotion ahoy!) I have bunch of Gradle builds related to web apps at my GitHub: http://git.io/eric in case that is what you're looking for.

Comment: This makes me loathe stackoverflow.  At a minimum 30 people think a question is useful and important,  but a single self-important administrator comes along and decides otherwise, and so the question gets canned.

Answer (score 22):

Most of the projects in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/bmuschko) are built with Gradle. You should find plenty of examples there. Three bigger example code bases that use Gradle are [Griffon](https://github.com/griffon/griffon), [Gaelyk](https://github.com/glaforge/gaelyk) and of course [Gradle itself](https://github.com/gradle/gradle). Also a [search for build.gradle on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=build.gradle&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) will find you a lot of other repositories.

Comment: Since the last autumn, Spring workgroup and OSGI workgroup work on Gradle, too

Answer (score 4):

I think the Spring's configuration is the best example: simple, clear and large. If you would like to see some exotic usages, including configuration-time task generation, you should take a look at [Hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm) and of course [Gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle) itself